# Namespacing issue in nested modules with for loop

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have coded a large Shiny app and I am modularising it with nested modules.

At the lower level, each module is taking care of coding for and returning a figure (`'Figure'` module). This module is called inside another module which structures the `'SubPanel'` where the figure is displayed along with titles, text, and legends. The `'SubPanel'` modules are called in the main app.

It all works fine except for one case where I use the same `'Figure'` module twice. Instead of repeating the same code, I made the `'Figure'` module call for another module using a `for` loop, thus adding yet another level of nesting.

### **Problem:**

When I run the app, there is no error and all the aesthetics, navbars, panels, titles, texts, legends and all work fine. **Yet the plots themselves do not show. I suspect that I do not handle the namespacing right**.

I have read several posts on SO about this but I can't seem to catch what I am doing wrong. I could surely use some another set of eyes on this. Any feedback is appreciated!

### Code:

**Main app (simplified)**

```
deployed <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1:10), 2),
                       y = rep(c(1:10), 2),
                       d = rep(c("A_site", "D_site"), each = 10))


# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  div(style = "padding: 1px 0px; width: '100%'", titlePanel(title = "")),
  
  navbarPage(
    title = div(strong("MY PROJECT"),
    tabPanel(title = "Data management",
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
        Panel2_SubPanel3_UI("MyData")
      )
    )
  )

)


# Main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  deplo <- reactive({deployed})
  Panel2_SubPanel3_Server("MyData", deplo)
  
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**SubPanel module:** organises the page into sections corresponding to the figures.

```
Panel2_SubPanel3_UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
     title = "Proximity data",
     sidebarPanel(width = 3, strong("The panel focuses on...")),
     mainPanel(width = 9, uiOutput(ns("both_deployed")))
  )
  
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Server <- function(id, deployed) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$both_deployed <- renderUI({
      Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_UI(session$ns("both_deployed"))
    })
    Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_Server("both_deployed", deployed())
    
  })
}
```

**Combined Figure module:** Creates all elements around a figure (title, text, placeholder, legend, etc.)

```
Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(width = 12,
             box(width = 12,
                 title = strong("..."),
                 p("Some text"),
                 h4("Figure 2:..."))),
    fluidRow(width = 12,
      lapply(c("a","d"), function(i) {
        uiOutput(ns(paste0('loggers_deployed_', i)))
      })
    ),
    h6("Some text")
  )
  
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_Server <- function(id, deployed) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    lapply(c("Arugot","David"), function(iii) {
      ccc <- paste0("loggers_deployed_", stringr::str_to_lower(stringr::str_extract(iii, "[A-Z]{1}")))     
      output[[as.character(ccc)]] <- renderUI({
        Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_UI(session$ns(ccc))
      })
      Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_Server(session$ns(ccc), deployed(), iii)    
    })
    
  })
}
```

**Last Figure module:** Generates the actual ggplot

```
Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  box(width = 6, 
    div(
      plotOutput(ns("loggers_deployed"), height = 400)
    )
  )
  
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_Server <- function(id, deployed, canyon) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$loggers_deployed <- renderPlot({
      fake_data <- deployed() %>% dplyr::filter(d == canyon)
      ggplot(fake_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + gem_point()
    })
    
  })
}
```

Comment: Try `uiOutput` instead of `plotOutput` in `div(plotOutput(ns(paste0('loggers_deployed_', i)), height = 400))` as you are using `renderUI`.

Comment: Thanks @YBS. It seems the problem did not come from this error though. I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some typos (gem_point) and issue in subsetting the data.  Try this

```
Panel2_SubPanel3_UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    title = "Proximity data",
    sidebarPanel(width = 3, strong("The panel focuses on...")),
    mainPanel(width = 9, uiOutput(ns("both_deployed"))
              
              )
  )
  
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Server <- function(id, deployed) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    output$both_deployed <- renderUI({ # print("Hello1")
      Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_UI(ns("both_deployed"))
    })
    Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_Server("both_deployed", deployed)
    
  })
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(width = 12,
             shinydashboard::box(width = 12,
                 title = strong("..."),
                 p("Some text"),
                 h4("Figure 2:..."))),
    fluidRow(width = 12,
             lapply(c("a","d"), function(i) {
               shinydashboard::box(width = 6, 
                   div(uiOutput(ns(paste0('loggers_deployed_', i)), height = 400)))
             })
    ),
    h6("Some text")
  )
  
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_Server <- function(id, deployed) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    lapply(c("Arugot","David"), function(iii) {
      ccc <- paste0("loggers_deployed_", stringr::str_to_lower(stringr::str_extract(iii, "[A-Z]{1}")))   
      
      output[[as.character(ccc)]] <- renderUI({ 
        Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_UI(session$ns(ccc))
      })
      Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_Server(ccc, deployed, iii)    
    })
    
  })
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_UI <- function(id) {
  
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("loggers_deployed"), height = 400)
  
}

Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_Server <- function(id, deployed, canyon) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observe({print(deployed())})
    output$loggers_deployed <- renderPlot({
      fake_data <- deployed() %>% dplyr::filter(d == canyon)
      ggplot(fake_data, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point() + labs(title = canyon)
    })
    
  })
}

deployed <- data.frame(x = rep(c(1:10), 2),
                       y = rep(c(1:10), 2),
                       # d = rep(c("A_site", "D_site"), each = 10)
                       d = rep(c("Arugot", "David"), each = 10)
                       )


# Main UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
  div(style = "padding: 1px 0px; width: '100%'", titlePanel(title = "")),

  navbarPage(
    title = div(strong("MY PROJECT"),
                tabPanel(title = "Data management",
                         tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                                     Panel2_SubPanel3_UI("MyData")
                         )
                )
    )

  )
)

# Main server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    deplo <- reactive({deployed})
    Panel2_SubPanel3_Server("MyData", deplo)
    
}
  
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: It works! Although the solution was in your answer, it was not related to the "gem_point" typo nor the subsetting issue of "deployed": in `Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2C_Server`, I initially wrote `Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_Server(session$ns(ccc), deployed, iii)` instead of `Panel2_SubPanel3_Figure2_Server(ccc, deployed, iii)`.